# Android Launch screen bug

Tags: android, react-native

I've modified `application theme` in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  </style>
```

Created file `res/drawable/splash_screen.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:gravity="center"
      android:src="@mipmap/background"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

Here the first bug goes. According to the tutorial i was using, this file should have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:gravity="center"
      android:src="@mipmap/background"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

But with this i'm always getting error during compilation:

```
res/drawable/splash_screen.xml:5:23-34 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/gray').
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
```

With my "edition" of this file, it at least goes well through compilation and installation.
So, how do i set background?

Second, the most important bug.
If the bg image is not covering entire screen, then on launch i see black background, and when app has been started, i see this:

[image]

The visible part of the app is the shape of the background image i'm using for launch screen. If i'm replacing it to bigger bg image (2000px+), then everything looks kind of ok, but i bet, putting huge bg image in there is not the right solution.
So, why this black "overlay" is appearing on top of my app ui?

Comment: Have you added a 'gray' color to your styles.xml or colors.xml?

Answer (score 0):

In your /res/values folder create a file colors.xml.

Than you can set your color like:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <color name="gray">#your_hex_code</color>
</resources>
```

This solved the problem for me. Hope helps you!